# Google Apps Script : Get row number matching value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm need some assistance in my problem.

I'm currently working on a script that works like this :

1. Send form
2. Lookup the value in table
3. Get the row number to use in another function

I have searched for the solution but mostly use logger to display value, I need the value as local variable to be used in other function.

Here is my current code up until the point I try to get row number :

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Nama = e.values[1];
  var Prinsipal = e.values[2];
  var Email = e.values[3];
  var Site = e.values[4];
  var Mobil = e.values[5];
  var Jumlah = e.values[6];
  var ETD = e.values[7];
  var ETA = e.values[8];
  var Keterangan = e.values[9];
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master Email Site');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var RowCabang = Site
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0] == Site){ //[0] because column A
      return i+1;
    }
  }
  var EmailCol = 2;
  var EmailDest = sheet.getRange(RowCabang, EmailCol).getValue();
```

With this script, the trigger is completed but it doesnt capture the row number as var to be used.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
  let RowCabang;
  data.some((row, index) => {
    if (row[0] === Site) {
      RowCabang = index + 1;
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was quick and accurate.